# Regularised regression code

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, matplotlib

I wrote some code to do regularised linear regression and it works, but I don't like the fact that I've had to double call the functions when plotting, nor the fact that I've sliced those calls to get the parts that I want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fit(phi_fn, xx, yy):
    w_fit = np.linalg.lstsq(phi_fn(xx), yy, rcond=None)[0]
    grid_size = 0.01
    x_grid = np.arange(0,9,grid_size)[:,None]
    f_grid = np.matmul(phi_fn(x_grid),w_fit)
    return(x_grid, f_grid)

def fitreg(phi_fn, xx, yy,lamb):
    yy = np.pad(yy,(0,8),'constant',constant_values=0)
    zz = np.concatenate((phi_fn(xx),lamb*np.identity(8)),axis=0)
    w_fit = np.linalg.lstsq(zz, yy, rcond=None)[0]
    grid_size = 0.01
    x_grid = np.arange(0,9,grid_size)[:,None]
    f_grid = np.matmul(phi_fn(x_grid),w_fit)
    return(x_grid, f_grid)

def phi_poly(xx):
        return np.concatenate([np.ones((xx.shape[0],1)), xx,xx**2,xx**3,xx**4,xx**5,xx**6,xx**7], axis=1)


D = 1
N = 10
mu = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

xx = np.tile(mu[:,None], (1, D)) + 0.01*np.random.randn(N, D)
yy = 2*xx + 2*np.random.randn(N,D)

plt.clf()
plt.plot(xx,yy,'kx')

plt.plot(fit(phi_poly, xx, yy)[0], fit(phi_poly, xx, yy)[1], 'b-')
plt.plot(fitreg(phi_poly, xx, yy,1)[0], fitreg(phi_poly, xx, yy,1)[1][:,0], 'r-')
plt.plot(fitreg(phi_poly, xx, yy,10)[0], fitreg(phi_poly, xx, yy,10)[1][:,0], 'g-')
plt.plot(fitreg(phi_poly, xx, yy,0.1)[0], fitreg(phi_poly, xx, yy,0.1)[1][:,0], 'y-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you test the code with the values you posted? When trying to run it, I currently get a `TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType` in the call to `np.linalg.lstsq`.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for me. Maybe my version of numpy is old, lemme go update.

Comment: FYI, I used `numpy` 1.13.3 in cPython 3.6.3

Comment: I'm using numpy 1.14.4 and python 3.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of some of the repetition using a `for` loop looping over the lambdas and colors and using tuple assignment to at least get rid of one level of having to use indexing as well as the necessity of having to call `fitreg` twice for each plot:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    D = 1
    N = 10
    mu = np.arange(10)

    xx = mu[:, None] + 0.01 * np.random.randn(N, D)
    yy = 2 * xx + 2 * np.random.randn(N, D)

    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(xx, yy, 'kx')

    x, y = fit(phi_poly, xx, yy)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'b-')
    for lamb, color in zip([1, 10, 0.1], "rgy"):
        x, y = fitreg(phi_poly, xx, yy, lamb)
        plt.plot(x, y[:, 0], '{}-'.format(color))

    plt.show()
```

I also added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script in another script and used [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for your `mu` array.

For the construction of `xx` you don't actually need the `numpy.tile`, the normal broadcasting rules already do that for you.